# Partitioning on a computed column

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Using - Oracle 11g

I have created a table say X. of this table, a column say C3 is a computed column which will have a value based on incoming values for the other 2 columns say C1 and C2. I am using a BEFORE INSERT trigger for the same.

The table is partitioned by Range on the computed column C3 and this is a Date column.

Now, when I try to insert data into the computed column using a Trigger, the system dumps all data into the default partition rather than creating individual partitions. Instead, when I use the computation formula directly in my Insert query; the partitioning is fine and as expected.

Any idea?

Thanx

Comment: It sounds like you haven’t set up interval partitioning and are just relying on the partitions you have manually set up. Set the interval if you want Oracle to automatically create the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like you are doing partitioning based on a virtual column.

[virtual_column_based_partitioning](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/partitioning-enhancements-11gr1.php#virtual_column_based_partitioning)